# Visualizing the Hubble Sphere

Tags: cosmology, speed-of-light, space-expansion, universe, cosmological-inflation

I have viewed the definitions of the Hubble Sphere and related cosmological concepts, as well as various explanations, yet Im still struggling to comprehend a full visualisation of this, which I would prefer instead of taking its word for it. To phrase the question that would most help me, the following follows: so from the moment that a celestial object crosses the hubble sphere boundary, as in going out of our hubble sphere scope, the images of that object will never reach us, the observer, from that point on, and we are left with a developing and cascading history of prior images only just reaching us now. If what I said is accurate, and requires no correction, my question now is how will the developing and changing history of past images for this celestial object play out in our view for the next millions of years until that moment in the old present where it crossed the Hubble Sphere boundary? How would it appear to us, the observer, over such a long term period? My intuition is telling me that such a celestial object will continue to age in our view of its past images, but also becoming increasingly redshifted until phoof, it is no longer visible due to being outside of the Hubble sphere.

Comment: Here is a video from PBS SpaceTime that talks about the most distant things we can see now and also the most distant things we will ever be able to see. It doesn't answer your question, but it set up coordinate systems you need for the answer. [How Much Of The Universe Can Humanity Ever See?](https://www.pbs.org/video/how-much-of-the-universe-can-humanity-ever-see-bboivw/)

Comment: Objects that are receding from us ever faster are being redshifted ever faster. That redshift becomes infinite after a finite time, i.e. such an object fades out, just like with the horizon of a black hole. I would say that your intuition is correct on that point. The "local" universe literally empties out, except for things that are gravitationally bound to us.

Answer (score 1):

> so from the moment that a celestial object crosses the hubble sphere boundary, as in going out of our hubble sphere scope, the images of that object will never reach us, the observer, from that point on, and we are left with a developing and cascading history of prior images only just reaching us now.

This is only accurate for the event horizon associated with dark energy, which coincides with the Hubble sphere in a dark energy-dominated universe. It's not a general feature of the Hubble sphere. For example, in a matter-dominated universe, the arbitrarily distant future of any object would always be visible to us after a sufficiently long time.

> My intuition is telling me that such a celestial object will continue to age in our view of its past images, but also becoming increasingly redshifted until phoof, it is no longer visible due to being outside of the Hubble sphere.

The image never "pops" out of view. It just becomes ever more redshifted and slowed in time (a redshifted scene is slowed to the same degree that the frequency of the light is slowed).

Since light is carried by discrete photons, there is in principle a last photon that we will ever receive from the object. But this would not be a sudden thing: the time between photons would have steadily increased to reach that point.